# WP Query misses post

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone explain to me why the following code misses one post? It returns only 3 posts although I specified 4 posts in the category `slide` under WordPress.

```
$gldcat = 'slide'; 

$gldct = '4';

$my_query = new WP_Query('category_name='.$gldcat.'&showposts='.$gldct.'');

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;

endwhile;
```

Thanks a lot for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

`showposts` is deprecated in favor of `posts_per_page`.  Try this:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('category_name='.$gldcat.'&posts_per_page='.$gldct.'');
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful input! Sorry it was an html fault by me

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was an html fault by me - the query is correct! I am now using `posts_per_page`.